# Trying to pack binary bits represented by bytes into a byte in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, binary, hex

I have a string that contains a string of hex values that represent binary bits, so 0x00 = binary 0 and 0x01 = binary 1. How can I pack eight of these hex values into a byte?

For example, the string = '\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01' and from that I want 0b11010101.

The end goal is to extract several bytes worth of binary from a long string.

How can this be done? I've not seen any instance so far of using struct.pack to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
3>> int('\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01'.translate({0: '0', 1: '1'}), 2)
213
```

Comment: This works well! As a side note I ended up having to split my input string into 8-byte chunks before applying this!